# RLS on report with multiple shared dataset

Tags: powerbi

Hi have 2 shared datasets example dataset 1 amd 2. On dataset 2 applied RLS with USERNAME().
Built report importing both as direct query and gave relationships. In service and desktop report report is working fine but in embedded application throwing error. Unexpected error something in inspect saying report token issue with workspace name. Can You help on this issue. Multiple shared datasets can't we use to build report with RLS USERNAME(). If need any more information I will share I'm details

Report is embedded in application.  In application report is bot working error is coming.